# Xamarin Forms Image not fitting to window on UWP app

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a simple page that is supposed to display an image. On my android app it fits to the phone screen, but on my UWP app running on a laptop the image expands out of the window. I have tried all different aspect options and different Horizontal and Vertical Orientation options with no luck.

My page looks like this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout >
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" >
            <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource LocalByteToImageFieldConverter}}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And the output looks like this:

Android:

[image: Android]

UWP:

[image: UWP]

I'm guessing its something small I'm missing but cannot find the right style settings.

Comment: Tried setting height and width?

Comment: @Luke You can also put image in Grid, then set `RowDefinition Height="Auto"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this , may be helpful for you

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOption="Fill" >
    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding ImageSource, 
           Converter={StaticResource LocalByteToImageFieldConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

try use Image Source="aa.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"